# Typescript: Filter array of conditional types AND have proper return type

Tags: arrays, typescript

I want to filter an array of conditional types AND have a proper return type. For example, take the following code:

```js
const foo = {
  type: "foo" as const,
  foo: 123
}

const bar = {
  type: "bar" as const,
  bar: 123
}

const arr = [foo, bar]

const filteredArr = arr.filter(val => val.type === 'foo');

filteredArr.map(val => {
  val.foo //Typescript blows up! Property foo does not exist on type
})
```

The only solution I've come up with is to cast the filtered array:

```js
type Foo = typeof foo;

const filteredArr = arr.filter(val => val.type === 'foo') as Foo[];
```

But it seems like there should be a way typescript would be smart enough to infer the array has been filtered down to only `Foo[]`.

Maybe some tricky usage of a user defined type guard?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firstly, the types of `foo` and `bar` should preserve the literal type for `type` so as to have a discriminated union (assuming you probably have type aliases or interfaces for these anyway).

`filter` will take a custom type guard but can't unfortunately infer a type guard from usage, so the function  `val => val.type === 'foo'` will not narrow the type down.

What we can do though is explicitly annotate the function to let the compiler know we are narrowing the type down in the function:

```
const foo = {
  type: "foo" as const, // added to preserve ,
  foo: 123
} 

const bar = {
  type: "bar" as const, // added to preserve 
  bar: 123
} 

const arr = [foo, bar]

const filteredArr = arr.filter((val): val is typeof foo => val.type === 'foo')

filteredArr.map(x => x.foo) // ok
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=15&ssc=34&pln=1&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBAZiEMC8MDeAoGMoE8AOApgFwwBECIZMAhhDKJFADQwD0btAJl4VzknwAnQhEJCAboRjMs8RKQCMAJgDMGAL4wMGRtBgAjGkJTo5eIqTJGh1Og3DRWHbr35RBIsZOlybStU1tXUdYYxNUAG1KVhsAXR09WDgASwAbKHE+AEEhCNo8gDpUjPEACjKJGjSASlIqtJgU+gtCEDh5JGQAPhgGwtaUZFQAckoRmp0SzJEuXKFCgFsafDKADxReteLEGvZOEABrIA)

Not sure it's a lot better than an assertion, but this is as close as you can get unfortunately.